# Get Items from Multiple Sharepoint List at once By List Name using CAML Query without any join operation

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to get items from multiple list of sharepoint at once using CAML query without any join operation. I have five list in sharepoint and while getting items from each list it's taking same amount of time as getting items from first list. Therefore i want to get multiple list items at once to save that time.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint online, you could use batch rest api.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis#example-requests-and-responses

[JavaScript demo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30044.sharepoint-online-performing-batch-operations-using-rest-api.aspx).

For on-premise, you could use [SPSiteDataQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms409088(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)